# Rails 3.1 not logging to Development.log in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rake tasks log to development just fine but when I go to run my app via Passenger nothing shows up in the log.

To answer a few common questions for people when this comes up:

I chmod 777 the log directory so access should not be an issue

My Passenger config is set to Development... at least I hope so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin blah@blah.blah

        ServerName blah.blah.blah
        DocumentRoot /var/www/qadashboard/public
        <Directory /var/www/qadashboard/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        RailsEnv development
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

        RailsBaseURI /crbagenda
        <Directory /var/www/crbagenda>
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql'  
gem 'rack-flash' 
gem 'rest-client' 
gem 'builder' 
gem 'chronic', "0.6.4" 
gem 'crack' 
gem 'nokogiri' 
gem 'jira4r' 
gem 'prawn' 
gem 'prawnto' #gem install may need to edit the date in rack-cache 1.0.3 gemspec 
gem 'websnap' 
gem 'whenever' #For cron jobs for the rake tasks 
gem 'execjs' 
gem 'therubyracer'  
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'json'

group :development, :test do   
     gem 'rspec-rails'   
     gem 'rspec'   
     gem 'ruby-breakpoint'   
     gem 'ruby-debug' 
end    

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

What else can I add?

Comment: Sorry my Gemfile came out poorly the first time around

Comment: Do you deploy via Capistrano?

Comment: Right now no... just copy the structure over vi cp <shame>

Comment: Please format your code using four-space indentation for codeblocks and backticks for inline code examples.

Comment: @RyanBigg should be good now... not sure what happened the first time around.

Comment: There's a weird bug in SO's formatting that doesn't format code that is nested within a list item.  I had to remove the list item to get it to format properly

Comment: @Matt it is still at zero bytes (as is Test)

Comment: Okay... rm -rf on log and then mkdir resolved it... I wonder if I had a felonious use of chmod...

Comment: @iWasRobbed Yeah I had to wait 8 hours to answer my own question as my rep was below 98. should be good to go now for answering and then in 24 hours I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I rm -rf the log directory and then mkdir log... now it works. Probably would have been a lot easier if I had been using Capistrano on this and not just copied the folder structure over. Been on Windows too long. Sigh.